# Ho to Disable "Wake on Any Key" on a Sony Vaio Running Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard, sleep, sony-vaio

I have a fairly old Sony Vaio laptop (model VGN-FW51MF) running Windows XP Professional SP3, which I re-installed myself from CD/DVD.  Most things seem to work fine but when I put it to sleep, it has this annoying habit of waking up if I happen to touch one of the keys on the keyboard.  I don't recall any of my other laptops doing this and I would really like to disable this behaviour but I can't find how.

I've run:

> powercfg /DEVICEQUERY wake_from_S3_supported

and the keyboard is not even in the list, and

> powercfg /DEVICEQUERY wake_armed

lists no devices at all, so I'm a bit stumped.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Check the bios for any settings in there.

Comment: That's actually rather normal behavior. I haven't known a computer that DIDN'T wake up when any key was pressed. Perhaps you were using Hibernate previously?

Comment: @music2myear most of the time even on hibernate it does that

Answer (score 0):

Did some searching and confirmed this.

Sleep and Hibernate has always awoken to all key strokes. This is the default and normal behavior in all OSes.

Solutions that offer specific keystroke wake-ups do not actually prevent the computer from waking up to other keys, but simply query the key that was pressed and if it doesn't correspond to the specified key or key combo, it puts the computer immediately back to sleep.

Unless your Vaio had a special utility or function built-in at the hardware or BIOS level, you may be misremembering or conflating another behavior with sleep.

Now, you can control the hardware that is allowed to wake the computer. In the Power Management control panel you should be able to tell the computer NOT to wake to mouse movement or input from specific other hardware elements, but this does NOT allow you to filter for specific keystrokes from the keyboard.